# Unable to move the button position to down

Tags: javascript, css

I am new to CSS.I am trying to move the position of button down which is overlapping with another button. I tried putting the button in different div, still facing the same issue. Below is my code

```
<div className="App">
      {!showEvents && (<div>
        <button onClick= {() => setShowEvents(true)}>Show Events </button>
      </div>)}
      {showEvents && (<div>
        <button onClick = {() => setShowEvents(false)}>Hide Events</button>
      </div>)}
      <Title title={title} />

      {showEvents && < Eventlist events={events} handleClick = {handleClick} />}
      
      {showModal && (
        <Modal handleClose={handleClose}>
          <h2>Terms and Conditions</h2>
          <p>Agree the terms and Conditions</p>
        </Modal>
      )}
      
      <div>
      
        <button1 onClick={() => setShowModal(true)}> Show </button1>
        </div>
      
    </div>
  );
}

// Export the App component to consume/ import the component in some other pages.
export default App;
```

CSS code for two buttons

```
button{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f1f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 40px;

}

button1{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f1f6;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 40px;

}
```

In the above code, I need to move button1 down from button. Can anyone help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Please show the rendered markup instead of the server-side template.

Comment: You need to add margin like: `margin: 10px 0 20px 0` property `(margin: top right bottom left)` on button then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is likely taking up the full space of the container div. Instead trying applying a margin to the container rather than the button

ie.

```
.button-div {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Comment: u mean to say need to add margin top, bottom in the button1 css?

Comment: It worked! So here setting the margin top 10 px and margin right 0, is my understanding rite, Can u pls help me to understand the above solution

Comment: Margin and padding takes 4 properties: top, right, bottom, left.

So, when setting these values you can pass in value and they will be applied like so:

- 1 value will be applied to all sides
- 2 values will be applied to (1st value) top and bottom and (2nd value) left and right
- 4 values and they will be applied respectively: 1st top, 2nd right, 3rd bottom, 4th left

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not applying a margin on the button. You are applying padding, which is spacing from the border of the button inside towards the content.

You need to apply margin to it and it will still work. Div is a block element so if you put margin it will just scale up to match the needed height.

Applying margin to the div is also correct though depending on what you are trying to accomplish.